# Get Date Limitation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So what I need is a limitation for the user of the funded contracts. So this is what I am trying to implement. I am trying to let the user enter dates within the year 2014, which will bring up how many funded contracts are there for each month. I ONLY want up to the last day of the previous month and the passed months within the year 2014. So for example we are in June, if the user inputs any dates that are before June he can see those months of how many funded contracts are in there - but not any contract from June.

So the user should not be able to see July until we hit August which we can see July from there. Here is my query.

I feel that my where clause for the `GetDate` is incorrect. Any help will be appreciated

```
          Alter Proc spGetAdminTotalYTD

           (@Begin_Date  DATETIME, 
            @End_Date DATETIME,
            @program int=null) As

    Begin
Declare @year int
Set @year = 2014

        SELECT  d.name, a.dealer_code, b.last_name, b.city, b.state, b.phone
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) Feburary
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November
            , COUNT(CASE WHEN  MONTH(c.Funded_date) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December,
            COUNT(1) AS YTD
        FROM tdealer a JOIN tContact b ON a.contact_id = b.contact_id 
             JOIN tContract  c ON a.dealer_id = c.dealer_id JOIN tCompany d 
             ON  c.company_id = d.company_id

       WHERE YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year
             AND c.Funded_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0,GETDATE())-4,0)
             AND c.Funded_date <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())-4,0)
             AND c.program_id = @program
             AND c.funded_date Between @Begin_Date And @End_Date

            GROUP BY
    d.name,
    a.dealer_code,
    b.last_name,
    b.city,
    b.state,
    b.phone
    END
```

Comment: If you want the current month and the passed months why should July be visible in August and not in July?

Comment: Because the month has to be a full month gone in order to see all the contracts funded. So if we are in June we shouldn't be able to see it because the month isn't over.

Comment: And I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: So, you do NOT want the current month. But only up to the last day of the previous month, right?

Comment: Correct, sorry If my explanation above didn't clarify that. I got a bit confused myself. But yes you are correct I need the last day of the previous month. My Where clause has a flaw in that which is where I am confused.

Comment: So if they run the query right now and `@begin_date` is Jan 13th at 4 PM and `@end_date` is now, you want everything from Jan 13th at 4 PM -> May 31st at 23:59:59.9999999? Or do you want the full month of whatever `@begin_date` is? What if the `@end_date` is May 12th at 6 PM, do you want everything from all of May or do you really want to observe the day and time too? I ask because it seems odd to have a report that shows data grouped by month, but some of those months might be partial...

Comment: Also can you explain the purpose of the -4? Are you trying to hard-code a maximum of 4 rows of output?

Comment: Yes actually it was originally suppose to be the full month for what ever the begin_date is. But Im starting to think it is a bit odd to do that. I'm actually starting to think the statement you made at first of "begin_date is Jan 13th at 4 PM and end_date is now, you want everything from Jan 13th at 4 PM -> May 31st at 23:59:59.9999999" is what I want. But as I explained earlier the datetime,datediff functions confuses me and you can see that in my where clause. Also for the -4 I was just confused I was trying to retrieve the last 4 months which isnt anything to do with how I want my query

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results on [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3)? I'm not quite clear exactly how YTD column is supposed to be calculated, for example.

Comment: For the YTD it just calculates the total of the funded contracts of the 12 months for 2014. I will provide more detail tomorrow and try to see if I can write the script on SQLfiddle for better clarity. Thanks for your help!

Comment: also for the YTD is does that for each company for the YTD. I have a parameter @program which allows the user select their company.

Comment: So YTD is for company, not company + dealer combination? Your current query has dealer_id in the group by, so it would return a separate YTD count for each company + dealer combination. This is getting more confusing every time you add details, so yes, sample data and desired results would be much more helpful. I'll post a query of what I *think* you want in the meantime, but you may be on your own to modify that as needed if you haven't described things adequately.

Comment: it is dealer, I am working on another report sorry. Its dealer not company. And okay thank you for your help. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are two very different databases.  Which one are you actually asking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

Try this procedure instead:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetAdminTotalYTD_AB -- always use schema prefix!
  @Begin_Date  DATETIME, 
  @End_Date    DATETIME,
  @program_id  INT = NULL -- use a name consistent with the column
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON; -- always use SET NOCOUNT ON and semi-colons

  DECLARE @year INT = 2014; -- why should this be hard-coded? 
                     -- So you can refactor the code in January? 
                     -- And again the following January?

  -- let's get the beginning of this year instead:
  DECLARE @thisyear DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 
    1-DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE()), DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()));

  -- if @Begin_Date pre-dates that, make it Jan 1:
  DECLARE @startrange DATETIME = CASE
    WHEN @Begin_Date < @thisyear THEN @thisyear ELSE @Begin_Date END;

  -- make sure the end of the range is actually at the
  -- end of the month *before* the end date they actually
  -- specify. Assumes they're basing this on GETDATE().
  -- If they pass the last day of the month, you may need
  -- to add logic to make that a valid selection.
  DECLARE @endrange DATETIME = DATEADD
  ( 
    DAY, 
    1-DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@End_Date),0)), 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,@End_Date), 0)
  );

  ;WITH x AS
  (
    SELECT company_id, dealer_id, 
      [Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],
      [Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec],

      -- to group YTD by company_id + dealer_id:
      YTD = [Jan]+[Feb]+[Mar]+[Apr]+[May]+[Jun]
           +[Jul]+[Aug]+[Sep]+[Oct]+[Nov]+[Dec]

      -- to group YTD by only company_id:
      YTD2 = SUM([Jan]+[Feb]+[Mar]+[Apr]+[May]+[Jun]
           +[Jul]+[Aug]+[Sep]+[Oct]+[Nov]+[Dec]) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Company_id)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT company_id, dealer_id,
        [Jan] = COALESCE([Jan],0), [Feb] = COALESCE([Feb],0), [Mar] = COALESCE([Mar],0),
        [Apr] = COALESCE([Apr],0), [May] = COALESCE([May],0), [Jun] = COALESCE([Jun],0),
        [Jul] = COALESCE([Jul],0), [Aug] = COALESCE([Aug],0), [Sep] = COALESCE([Sep],0),
        [Oct] = COALESCE([Oct],0), [Nov] = COALESCE([Nov],0), [Dec] = COALESCE([Dec],0)
      FROM
      (
        SELECT m = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,
                   DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,Funded_date), 0)),3),
          company_id, 
          dealer_id, 
          mc = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.tContract
        WHERE program_id = @program_id
          AND Funded_date >= @startrange
          AND Funded_date < @endrange -- don't use BETWEEN for range queries
        GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,
            DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,Funded_date), 0)),3),
          company_id, 
          dealer_id
      )
      AS x
      PIVOT 
      (
        MAX(mc) FOR m IN 
        (
          [Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Apr],[May],[Jun],
          [Jul],[Aug],[Sep],[Oct],[Nov],[Dec]
        )
      ) AS p
    ) AS y
  ) 
  SELECT 
    comp.name, deal.dealer_code, -- don't use meaningless aliases like a,b,c,d
    cont.last_name, cont.city, cont.[state], cont.phone, 
    x.[Jan],x.[Feb],x.[Mar],x.[Apr],x.[May],x.[Jun],
    x.[Jul],x.[Aug],x.[Sep],x.[Oct],x.[Nov],x.[Dec],
    x.YTD, x.YTD2
  FROM x
  INNER JOIN dbo.tDealer AS deal
  ON x.dealer_id = deal.dealer_id
  INNER JOIN dbo.tCompany AS comp
  ON x.company_id = comp.company_id
  INNER JOIN dbo.tContact AS cont
  ON deal.contact_id = cont.contact_id;
END
GO
```

Many of the comments have a lot of background, and it's not just me ranting about how you should write code like I do:

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)
- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Ladies and gentlemen, start your semi-colons!](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons)
- [My stored procedure "best practices" checklist](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

If you are already specifying the year, than you can keep it simple by removing

```
AND c.Funded_date >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-4, 0)
```

If you are just looking to get the first day of the month, this might be a simple approach:

```
DATEADD(day,-(DAY( getdate())-1) ,Convert(date,getdate()))
```

So the new WHERE clause could look like:

```
WHERE YEAR(c.Funded_date) = @Year 
AND c.Funded_date < DATEADD(day,-(DAY( getdate())-1) ,Convert(date,getdate()))
and c.program_id = @program 
And c.funded_date Between @Begin_Date And @End_Date
```